# How to join fetch an attribute of element in collection with QueryDSL JPA

Tags: jpa, join, many-to-many, querydsl

Entities as below:

```
class A {
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "rel_a_b", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
    Set<B> bSet;
}

class B {
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bSet")
    Set<A> aSet;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "rel_b_c", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id"))
    Set<C> cSet;
}

class C {
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cSet")
    Set<B> bSet;
}
```

I need to select `A` entities and join fetch `bSet` and `cSet` in `B` entity. Using JPA Criteria, codes as below:

```
    final Fetch<A, B> bSetFetch = rootA.fetch("bSet", JoinType.LEFT);
    bSetFetch.fetch("cSet", JoinType.LEFT);
```

are working perfectly, but I can't achieve this with QueryDSL. I tried

```
    final QA a = QA.a;
    jpaQuery
    .from(a)
    .leftJoin(a.bSet, QB.b).fetchJoin()
    .leftJoin(QB.b.cSet).fetchJoin()
    .select(a)
```

but it throws exception that

```
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=b,role=A.b,tableName=`b`,tableAlias=b4_,origin=a a2_,columns={a2_.id ,className=B}}] [select a
from A a
  left join fetch a.bSet as b
  left join fetch b.cSet]]
```

, if without `fetchJoin()`, the results don't include `bSet` and `cSet`. Could anyone solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fetch joins are applied correctly from a QueryDSL point of view. We can also observe this from the fact that the produced JPQL query looks correct.

The limitation here is that Hibernate only allows FETCH JOINS if the owner of the fetch association is projected in the select clause. `cSet` is an association on `B`, so you would need to project your `b`'s or omit the fetch join for `cSet`. For example:

```
jpaQuery
    .from(a)
    .leftJoin(a.bSet, QB.b).fetchJoin()
    .leftJoin(QB.b.cSet).fetchJoin()
    .select(a, b)
```

Now this will result in duplicate results for `a` due to the cardinality of `bSet`. That is just a limitation of fetch joins in Hibernate.

Alternatively, you could consider specifying a fetch graph for the query:

```
EntityGraph postGraph = em.getEntityGraph("post");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", postGraph);
```

For more information on using EntityGraphs see https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph